# Using XPath To Extract Data

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to use XPath to extract data in a webpage but get nothing, how do I extract the data?

I tried using the below codes but they return nothing.

I tried using

```
house.xpath('.//span[@class = "icon icon-pin"]/text()').extract_first()

and

house.xpath('.//span[@class = "ann info-item"]/text()').extract_first()
```

but I get nothing.

Here is the code that I want to extract:

```
<span class = "ann-info-item">
     <span class = "icon icon-pin">
         ::before
       </span>
       " San Jorge "
      </span>
```

I want to extract " San Jorge " but I get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should select internal `span` and then take following text, so the expression will be like `house.xpath('.//span[@class="icon icon-pin"]/following-sibling::text()').get()`

In shell I could get data in this way:

```
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> txt = """<span class = "ann-info-item">
...      <span class = "icon icon-pin">
...          ::before
...        </span>
...        " San Jorge "
...       </span>"""
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> sel.xpath('//span[@class="icon icon-pin"]/following-    sibling::text()').get()
u'\n       " San Jorge "\n      '
>>> sel.xpath('//span[@class="icon icon-pin"]/following-sibling::text()').get().strip()
u'" San Jorge "'
```

Comment: Thanks! very useful. Can you explain why following-sibling::text() works? I mean, I understand that <span class = "icon icon-pin"> is a child not a sibling?

Comment: Check once again, we have `ann-info-item` parent and inside we have two "objects": span `icon-pin` and text. Take a look on closing tags. Text stands _after_ the inner span. So, we use `following-sibling` selector here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.//span[@class = "ann-info-item"]/text()[2]
```

It looks like you dropped a '-' in your second xpath query.  Additionally the amn-info-item classed span has two text nodes. Using the [2] will get the second one.